# How to check if a checkbox is checked in GWT?

Tags: checkbox, gwt

In my project, I have this checkbox:

```
<g:CheckBox ui:field="answer"></g:CheckBox> <span class="{style.answer-font}">arithmetische Operatoren</span>
```

And this button:

```
<g:Button ui:field="abgabe" styleName="{style.button} bg-success text-white">ICH BIN FERTIG!</g:Button>
```

When the user presses the button and the checkbox is checked, it should trigger a window alert:

```
Button abgabe;
CheckBox answer;

@UiHandler("abgabe")
void check(ClickEvent e) {
    if (answer.isChecked()==true)
        Window.alert("HALLO");
}
```

Why does it not work?

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to mark your variables to be bound by the UiBinder. Just add `@UiField` annotations to both `Button abgabe` and `CheckBox answer` declarations, like this:

```
@UiField
Button abgabe;
@UiField
CheckBox answer;
```

BTW: `answer.isChecked()` is deprecated. Use `answer.getValue()` instead. And you don't have to compare boolean value with `true` in `if` clause. `if(answer.getValue())` is good enough.

Comment: please look in the comments, why this dont work for me

Comment: @LukasBierwirth which comments? This answer looks right to me.

Answer (score -1):

boolean task1 = false;

```
@UiHandler("abgabe")
void checkTasks(ClickEvent e)
{
    checkTask1();
    if (task1 == true)
        Window.alert("Richtig");
    else
        Window.alert("Falsch");
}

void checkTask1()
{
        if(answer1.getValue())
        task1 = true;
    
}
```

Comment: Is `answer1` declared with `@UiField`annotation as I suggested in my answer??